# Which Node module or JS code to use in order to send Push Notification (via FCM) to Android device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to find easiest and most reliable way to send Push Notifications (PN) to Android (with newer FCM) using JavaScript.

Does anyone have experience which Node module is good for Android for FCM?

Or maybe is better to use just a regular POST request to Google service? (is there a working example for this way just to confirm?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has an Admin SDK for Node, which had built-in support for [sending messages through Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages).

But you can't (and shouldn't try to) use this in an Android app that you send to regular users of your app. The Admin SDK runs with administrative privilege on your Firebase project, so it should only be run in a trusted environment (such as a Node.js server you control, or in Cloud Functions).